# GoogleMap won' t appear in an Alpha release

Tags: android, google-play, google-maps-android-api-2

I have a GoogleMap in my Android app. When I give another user an apk by email, the GoogleMap works fine. When I export the apk and upload it as an alpha to the Play Store, the map is blank. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you through the [The Google Maps API Key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#the_google_maps_api_key) section and generate a key for your release certificate?

Comment: Yes. If I hadn't the map wouldn't ever work on any device.

Comment: Have you used two different certificates for API key and signing the app...?

Comment: @KairisCharm: I'm not referring to the map, but rather the map *key* that is based on the certificate you signed the exported apk with...

Comment: I know what you meant. I needed that key to get maps to run in testing altogether.

Answer (score 2):

For Alpha release or Inter App Sharing Google different SHA1. you need to add these SHA1 into your Key.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Never mind. The problem was that my boss was the only one testing through Play Store, but he never did a complete reinstall. Once he uninstalled and reinstalled by way of the Play Store, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

When you export the APK, you use a different signing key than the default used when you normally run via your favourite IDE.

There need to be an entry in [Google APIs Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console/) for each signing key and package pair.

Comment: But when I manually push the exported APK to a device and install that way, the maps work. It's only going through the Play Store that breaks it.

Answer (score 0):

When you upload alpha release then playstore changes the SHA-1
You can get the changed SHA-1 from the APP CERTIFICATE TAB
See the image below

[image]